# Custom LinkedHashMap Concurrency

Tags: java

What is the best approach to making this custom LinkedHashMap custom cache example thread safe?

```
 public class Cache extends LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4297992703249995219L;
        private final int cacheSize;
        public Cache(int size){
            super(size + 1, .75f, true); 
            this.cacheSize=size;
        }

         protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Object, Object> eldest) {
            return size() > cacheSize;
         }
    }


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cache cache = new Cache(2);
        cache.put(1, "one");
        cache.put(2, "two");

        for(Entry<Object, Object> entry : cache.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread-safety is _hard_.  Use `ConcurrentHashMap<>`.

Comment: Best? It's either thread safe or its not.

Comment: There are usually several ways to make something thread safe and some are better than others

Comment: Your `removeEldestEntry`-function is confusing me. It sounds like it should do something, which I cannot see that it does: remove the eldest entry.

Comment: removeEldestEntry is called automatically by the LinkedHashMap impl and evicts the cache object

Comment: @MitchWheat Are you suggesting that, for instance, `ConcurrentHashMap` offers no advantages over `Collections.synchronizedMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ConcurrentHashMap is very similar to the HashMap class, except that ConcurrentHashMap offers internally maintained concurrency. It means you do not need to have synchronized blocks when accessing ConcurrentHashMap in multithreaded application.

```
//Initialize ConcurrentHashMap instance
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

//Print all values stored in ConcurrentHashMap instance
for each (Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet())
{
system.out.println(e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue());
}
```

Above code is reasonably valid in multi-threaded environment in your application. The reason, I am saying “reasonably valid” is that, above code yet provides thread safety, still it can decrease the performance of application. And ConcurrentHashMap was introduced to improve the performance while ensuring thread safety.

To improve it's performace you can adjust following parameters as per your need:

- initialCapacity
- loadFactor
- concurrencyLevel

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you follow SLaks's suggestion in the comments and use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or other data structures from the concurrent library, rather than attempting the much more difficult task of making a non-concurrent data structure thread-safe.

One solution is to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` - whenever you add a key-value pair to the map, add its key to the queue as well, and poll the queue to remove the oldest map entry.  One potential complication is that your threads' interleaving will cause an object to be added to the map prior to its being added to the queue - I don't consider this to be a problem, as you only need the queue's order to approximately match the order in which key-value pairs are added to the map.

This solution is problematic if you want to be able to remove key-value pairs from the map before they've expired, because you may need to traverse the entire queue to remove the keys that you've removed from the map.  The simplest solution to this problem is to never remove keys from the queue except by polling it (i.e. if you remove a key-value pair from the map, then don't remove the key from the queue) - you'll have a few keys in the queue that don't correspond to keys in the map, but this is only a problem in that it results in the queue being larger than it needs to be - the correctness of the map isn't compromised.

Answer (score 1):

I had a long complicated answer here, but then I realized it's really just the same thing as saying:

```
Map<K,V> myMap = Collections.<K,V>synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<K,V>());
```

myMap is now a thread-safe LinkedHashMap.  No need to create a new class.